# Почему некоторые вопросы выделяются отдельным цветом

Tags: поддержка, метки, дизайн, избранные-метки

Листая вопросы, стало интересно, почему некоторые из них выделяются отдельным цветом (см. скриншот). Особо вроде бы они ничем не не отличаются. Таким цветом могут быть отмечены как вопросы с принятыми и не принятыми ответами, так и вопросы вообще без ответов, редактированные и нет..

В чем отличие этих вопросов от неподсвеченных?

[image: скриншот из ru.stackoverflow]

Comment: Вопросы с избранными метками

Comment: @АндрейNOP, получается при переходе в какую-то определенную метку подсвечиваться будут вопросы, которые пересекаются с другими метками из списка отслеживаемых, верно?

Comment: Именно так, если будете смотреть вопросы по тем меткам, то будет подсвечиваться те, что имеют какую-нибудь метку из избранных помимо этих трёх

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> почему некоторые из них выделяются отдельным цветом

Это вопросы на которых есть отслеживаемые вами метки.

> получается при переходе в какую-то определенную метку подсвечиваться будут вопросы, которые пересекаются с другими метками из списка отслеживаемых, верно?

Верно.